# nwjs / node webkit display scrollbars

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

For some reason it doesn't show me any scrollbars.
The overflowing content is simply hidden.

Middle-clicking with the mouse allows to scroll. It's just that the scrollbars are hidden.

Tried with CSS:

`body: {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
}`

The above displays a disabled/useless scrollbars, that is I resize the window but the scrollbars stay nonfunctional.

This issue is barely mentioned online.

Using nwjs-v0.12.3-win-x64.

Does anyone know a solution? I just want simple scrollbars.

**The complete code is on**: https://jsfiddle.net/rtk1ebg1/

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "hello",
    "main": "index.html",
    "window": {
        "title": "Hey!",
        "icon": "icon.png",
        "toolbar": true,
        "position": "center"
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also mention that this is a very simple HTML page with no CSS modifications. It's in out-of-the-box state.

Comment: When you open the page in chrome, do you see a scrollbar? post your complete code on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Checking it right now @Kuf , will report soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Kuf check out the edit - I put the complete code on jsFiddle, and added the package.json file. It's the whole app. Let me know what you find. Thank you!

Comment: Tested on WinXP: It DOES show scrollbars. (original post is based on Win8.1). On the Win8.1 machine I do not have Chrome for testing. On the WinXP one I do and it does show scrollbars, normally.

Comment: I have the same bug on the same setup.
Still havent figured it out. It's definitely an nwjs bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
body {
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Edited(forgot the main lines)

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Don't know I don't have this problem in my project, but i looks like bug

Comment: Thanks for trying, anyway.